# Half circle button match circular image android

Tags: android, image, button, match, rounded-corners

What is the best way to implement the below graphics in android?

[image]

For the image view I am using

```
de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
```

I need to have a button over the bottom 1/3 of the image view and match the curve. Is there a way similar to iOS where I can place the two in a layout and then just set the curve of the layout and clip to bounds? Or what is the best way to solve this? I do have an xml file for the button and I can get a match if I cover half the image, but have not been able to figure out less than that. Here is my button shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="5dp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="1000dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="1000dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/transparent_lightGray" />
</shape>
```

Comment: try masking the layout create a custom view

Comment: https://github.com/christophesmet/android_maskable_layout

Comment: @FaisalNaseer Ahhh, thanks. I will give that a try.